# How to get zenhub issues related to an epic with the API?

Tags: zenhub

When I view an epic in the ZenHub dashboard, I can see the issues which relate to an epic. It seems these can be added/removed using the REST API described here:

https://github.com/ZenHubIO/API#add-or-remove-issues-to-epic

Is there also an REST API which allows for the retrieval of the epic issues?

It seems the GraphQL API described [here](https://developers.zenhub.com/) is a little more feature rich but I was unable to locate the reference documentation which describes the query I am looking for. It appears that the  Explorer feature could be used to locate the right schema information, but it seems this is not available on ZenHub Enterprise?